# Reasoning and Explanation for $2/3-1/2$

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

> Denise says that $2/3-1/2 = 1/3$ and gives the reasoning indicated in Figure (below) to support her answer.
>
> Is Denise right?  If not, what is wrong with her reasoning and how could you help her understand her mistake and fix it?

[image: pie]

Please, don't just explain how to solve the problem correctly; explain where Denise's reasoning is flawed.

I know that $2/3-1/2$ is $1/6$ but need help with the rest of the problem.

The Figure  is of a circle cut into $3$ parts and it has $2$ of the parts shaded to represent $2/3$ and then she takes away half of the shade away and says she has $1/3$ left or $1/3$ shaded.

Comment: Is the amount she takes away $\dfrac12$ or $\dfrac12 \times \dfrac23$?

Comment: Imagine that she is supposed to take away half of the whole circle, and the half that is taken away must be entirely contained with the $\frac 23$ that is present.

Comment: Here mistake is that she takes half of the shade away. She should take half of the complete circle away.